# Issue while using CLI dataloader

Tags: data-loader

I am getting this error while running my process in CLI dataloader:

> c:\Program Files\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin>process.bat
>   accountExtract 2013-10-15 15:26:27,695 INFO  [main]
>   controller.Controller initLog (Controller.java:389) -  Using built-in
>   logging configuration, no log-conf.xml in c:\Program
>   Files\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin\log-conf.xml 2013-10-15
>   15:26:27,712 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initLog
>   (Controller.java:391) - The log has been initialized 2013-10-15
>   15:26:27,722 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initConfig
>   (Controller.java:327) - config dir created at c:\Program
>   Files\salesforce.com\Da ta Loader\bin\accountExtract 2013-10-15
>   15:26:27,732 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initConfig
>   (Controller.java:338) - config file created at c:\Program
>   Files\salesforce.com\D ata Loader\bin\accountExtract\config.properties
>   2013-10-15 15:26:27,761 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initConfig
>   (Controller.java:355) - The controller config has been initialized
>   2013-10-15 15:26:27,766 INFO  [main] process.ProcessRunner run
>   (ProcessRunner.java:116) - Initializing process engine 2013-10-15
>   15:26:27,772 INFO  [main] process.ProcessRunner run
>   (ProcessRunner.java:119) - Loading parameters 2013-10-15 15:26:27,776
>   INFO  [main] config.LastRun load (LastRun.java:96) - Last run info
>   will be saved in file: c:\Program Files\salesforce.com\Data
>   Loader\bin\accountExtract null_lastRun.properties
>   *2013-10-15 15:26:27,806 FATAL [main] process.ProcessRunner topLevelError (ProcessRunner.java:238) - Unable to run process null*
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No
>   enum const class com.salesforce.dataloader.action.OperationInfo.
>           at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:162)
>           at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:100)
>           at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.java:253)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class
>   com.salesforce.dataloader.action.OperationInfo.
>           at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
>           at com.salesforce.dataloader.config.Config.getEnum(Config.java:436)
>           at com.salesforce.dataloader.config.Config.getOperationInfo(Config.java:976)
>           at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:123)
>           ... 2 more

**This is the process-conf.xml file I am using:**

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">                 
<beans>                 
    <bean id="accountExtract" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner" singleton="false">                
        <description>To take test extract for Note Object</description>                 
        <property name="name" value="accountExtract"/>                  
        <property name="configOverrideMap">                 
           <map>                    
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="true"/>      
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="E:\DoCss\Script Work\CLI-data loader\debuglog.log"/>         

                <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://servername.salesforce.com"/>  
                <entry key="sfdc.username" value="chirag.verma@servername"/>                                    
                <entry key="sfdc.password" value="944ef664cf45a36a56a9c9231f9c04f74e469aecd5114a7971458ad280d4cb56968fdeb048d283eea9ed9591e8253634"/>   
                <entry key="process.encryptonKeyFile" value="E:\DoCss\Script Work\CLI-data loader\key.txt"/>    

                <!-- <entry key="dataAccess.readBatchSize" value="200"/> -->    
                <entry key="sfdc.enableLastRunOutput" value="true"/>    
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="500"/> <!-- same as 'Query request size in DL' -->   

                <entry key="sfdc.truncateFields" value="true"/> 
                <!-- <entry key="" value=""/> -->   

                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Account"/>  
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 10000"/>   
                <entry key="process.operation" value="Extract"/>                    
                <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="E:\DoCss\Script Work\CLI-data loader\Note_Extract.csv"/>                    
                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>                 
                <entry key="dataAccess.writeUTF8" value="true" />   

                <entry key="process.statusOutputDirectory" value="E:\DoCss\Script Work\CLI-data loader\logs_success-error"/>    
                <!--<entry key="process.outputSuccess" value="E:\DoCss\Script Work\CLI-data loader\logs_success-error\csvUpsertProcess_success.csv"/>   
                <entry key="process.outputError" value="E:\DoCss\Script Work\CLI-data loader\logs_success-error\csvUpsertProcess_error.csv"/>
           </map>                   
        </property>                 
    </bean>                 
</beans>
```

DataLoader ver. 27

Please help me ASAP if possible.

Comment: servername.salesforce.com is not a valid endpoint. Have you tried login.salesforce.com (production) or test.salesforce.com (sandbox)?

Comment: Yes I have tried this also, I am getting the same error with this also. @Peter

Answer (score 3):

The key error appears to be mapping a Java Enum value to a value in XML config file.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class com.salesforce.dataloader.action.OperationInfo. at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)

Specifically the OperationInfo enum.

Having had a peak into this Enum I can see it requires the following values...

```
insert, 
update, 
upsert, 
delete, 
hard_delete, 
extract, 
extract_all
```

Since Java is case senstiive by default, the following part of your config will need to change to using a value from the above....

```
<entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
```

The Salesforce documentation gives one example of this in this topic [Data Loader Process Configuration Parameters](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=loader_params.htm).

[image]

However the linked topic, [Data Loader Command Line Operations](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=loader_operations.htm&language=en_US), gives only the labels of these values and not the actual config values needed, which I agree is confusing and misleading in the context from which the page was linked. Hopefully the above list gives future readers the mapping they need! :)

Comment: ok...Let me try this and will get back to you if still any issue arise.

Comment: Did you mean to paste the new error in? I cannot see it?

Comment: I am getting the same ERROR even after doing changes... :(

> <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>

Comment: Sorry to ask, but just in case, have been sure to changed it in all areas of your XML config file?

Comment: "in all the areas" mean, can you elaborate !
As there is only one command in which we have to specify the operation type.
Shall i show you my process-conf.xml file again ?

Comment: In your process-conf.xml file.

Comment: As per me, I have done the changes in all the areas...but still I am checking my file again for any such issue.

Also in the error: Why I am getting this line  Unable to run process **null** <br/> Why it is giving my process name as **null** rather my process name is **accountExtract**

Comment: I suspect that maybe related to the other error....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11084/discussion-between-andrew-fawcett-and-chirag-verma)

Comment: Hi > @Andrew Fawcett
We are you available on Chat?
Can you tell me the approx time.

Comment: I'll go in now.

Comment: I am there only, Please reply.